# Why is my site getting error reports from users with iOS7 on a MacBook?

Tags: safari, ios

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449512/why-would-anyone-run-ios7-on-a-macbook) already on Stackoverflow though got referred to this forum here.

I got a list of Safari bugs that happened on a MacBook running iOS7. I am a bit confused now as afaik iOS7 is an operating system for iPads and iPhones only - or am I wrong?

PS: I am aware that my question might sound a bit odd but I am used to Windows (cough, cough) and don't know much about Macs and their operation systems.

Comment: It sounds like an error.  There are plenty of mac users who do not know that the ipad and Mac use different operating systems or exactly what they are called.

Comment: Could it be that they are using the Xcode simulator? I agree with @TomG, I can't imagine how one would get iOS to run on a Mac (other than the simulator).

Comment: I would say that people setting the User Agent (as discussed by @MK) is most likely. I have been routinely browsing with User Agent of an iPad to watch videos on sites that want Flash by default, but don't require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruling out a possible hack to get iOS to run on a MacBook natively (which would get a lot of publicity), I can see the following options

- Users didn't know enough about their system and just picked the things most likely (which means that you could have error reports from users with OS X 10.7 on a MacBook as well as from some with iOS7 on an iDevice mixed together)
- One or the other is just the default option when filling in a bug report on wherever you are getting them from and people are lazy
- Users have been accessing your site via the iOS simulator on OS X. Possible but rather unlikely (unless you have a very special site :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no publicly known way of running iOS 7 on a MacBook. As you've said, iOS 7 is a mobile OS used on iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch devices. Macs use different versions of OS X.

Depending on how you're getting these bug reports, here's what users may be doing and what you could do:

1. Entering incorrect information in the bug report - just ask your users about the browser configuration and hardware in use (you could also provide them instructions to get the Safari version).
2. Configuring custom (and possibly invalid) user agent strings to indicate iOS 7 on MacBook, which you've gathered from logs - examine the user agent to check for the presence of "Mobile" anywhere (indicating it's from an iOS device) or the absence of it.

Here's the list of [Safari User Agent Strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/). You could try to link the user agent with a specific user by communicating with a user and having a test session.